# How to create a custom metric for GA in GTM, this custom metrics should increment everytime the event action "TEST" is fired

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How to create a custom metric for GA in GTM this custom metrics should increment every time the event action TEST is fired

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the custom metric in Google Analytics. Go to property settings, custom definitions, custom metrics. Click "new metric", provide name and scope. Make a note of the numeric index that is given to your new metric, you need that to adress the field in GTM.

In GTM go to your Analytics tag that fires your event. In "More settings" look for "custom metrics". Click "new custom metric". In the first field enter the numeric index for your metric (see above), in the second enter the number "1". This number will be added to the metric in GA every time the tag is fired.

If you use a Google Analytics settings variable in GTM you need to check "enable overwriting settings for this tag" to access the "More settings" pane.

Comment: I would want this custom metric to fire on a specific event action, my event tag has multiple event actions, if I set up as you've mentioned, I believe it will fire for all the other event actions as well